# Excel 2010 add and delete rows is very slow but calculations is not

Tags: excel, performance

Help!

I have an 8MB 2010 .xslx workbook (no macros) that runs a full calc in about 2 seconds. It only 2 worksheets each with less than 1,500 rows. However, it has 100 and 200 columns. It takes 20+ seconds to insert or delete a row (and much much longer when I delete a group of rows).

It does have a fair amount of calculations in the workbook largely made up of index/match formulas. I went a process to simplify that process by only calculating the matches (for the most part) at the top and left of the worksheet. For example, All of F7:DV7 will point to only 2 rows on worksheet 2 so the match() is only done once in column C and D.

I realize index/match is more complicated than simple a+b and that excel likes rows more than columns but this file isn't that big at all and it seems like it should be able to handle it. And the fact that the calculation is fine, it's just when I add/delete rows that it's so slow has me bewildered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply pnuts. I meant to address those questions. Yes I tried without calculations and it didn't seem to help. But it doesn't seem calculations are struggling. Conditional Formatting - none. Though I do have some basic number and some color formatting.
The GoTo is the same thing as Control-End? To see if there are extra columns/rows? It goes to where I would expect. One sheet goes to GV1253 and the other to DV1335

Comment: I will look over that now, I have not seen that one yet.

Comment: Yeah I found that one shortly after going to your link. Just like most things I've seen, everything address calculation time, which isn't bad on my workbook. It's not instant but the full recalc is 2 seconds.

Comment: I did see however that it confirms index is NOT a volatile function which I thought might be an issue having so many. I'm still stumped, I don't know why adding a row would take 10X longer than a full recalc.

Comment: But aren't there people out there that have 100X has many rows (mine is only 1500), everything would take hours. There's something else at play here..

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue recently, and I found this question while searching for an answer online. Unfortunately, it didn't include an answer, so I moved on. However, I found the reason why the worksheet I was working on was taking so long to delete rows and wanted to return to this question and add my 2 cents.

In my case, it turned out one of the vlookup formulas included table array written something as SheetName!$A$1:D5000. When the formula was copied down, the range expanded by one in every cell down. So the next cell down had defined table array as SheetName!$A$1:D5001. And this went on for a few thousand rows. Turning off automatic calculation had no effect on reducing the wait whenever deleting rows.

Anyway, changing the table array in the vlookup to SheetName!A:D and copying that vlookup down the column did the trick. You didn't mention you used a vlookup, but it could be happening in the index/match formulas.

Answer (score 0):

this is an areas problem. When you filter your data and select an entire column, you are selecting multiple non contiguos ranges, i.e multiple areas. A workaround could be:

- sort your data from a to z to group the rows you want to delete in
  only one area
- Filter the values you want to delete
- Delte rows
- Enjoy!

If the actual order of your data is important to you, just add a column, fill it with numbers from 1 to n. Perform steps 1) 2) and 3), then restore the original order. Perform step 3).